# samsung grand duos 9082 doesn't see that my SD card is encrypted on it and there is no option to decrypt

Tags: settings, security

I encrypted my samsung grand duos 9082 and then my SD card, using the settings for encryption. But then, to unlock screen, I decrypted my handset and I unlocked it by my samsung account. Then, the password was removed without to decrypt SD card. At now, the handset doesn't see that my SD card is encrypted on it and there is no option to decrypt the files on my SD card. I know my password, but there is no place to input to unlock the files. Please, help to decrypt my files on SD card.